# sudo apt-get install problem

Tags: apt, kubuntu, xserver

I installed amd proprietary driver and when reboot, xserver wont come up.
After that I purged xserver and proprietary driver and try to install xserver again.
But it wont work.
apt-get install wont work. It says `has no installation candidate` or

```
reading package lists... Done
Building dependency treee
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and  not upgraded
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`? If that fails, please add the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` might not be the best thing to do. It won't improve the situation.

Comment: Problem is that sudo apt-get install whatever wont work. Like computer isnt on internet.

Comment: Are you unable to get to a desktop?

Answer (score 0):

AMD graphices drives? You must remove Ubuntu system drives first:

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx* 
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Then go to the AMD website, and download your drivers.